# How to update the JRE in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

So, I ran my Projects in `Eclipse` with a Run Configuration that used the `JRE 1.8_40`, but I update it to `1.8_45` and `Eclipse` says this:

> Unable to locate executable for jre1.8.0_40

Because when I installed the `_45` version Java told me If  I wanted to clean the system by deleting the old Java Versions, thinking that Eclipse was smart and knew that I update it, but no, now I get that annoying Error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Go to `Windows > Preferences`.
- Locate `Java > Installed JREs`. (Or simply type `JREs` in the search box).
- The screen will show the list of JREs.
- Click on `Add` button, locate the new folder on your machine and select.
- Remove the old JRE from the list.

Answer (score 1):

> Window-->Preferences-->Java-->Installed JREs-->Add... - Right click on
>   your project-->Build Path-->Configure Build Path-->Add library-->JRE
>   system library-->next-->WorkSpace Default JRE