# JavaFX failing due to wrong JRE? Maybe? Error: LinkageError / java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:

Tags: eclipse, javafx

My attempts to learn JavaFX are proving futile due to Eclipse schenanigans

I'm trying to follow TheNewBoston's JavaFX tutorial (found at https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGBzfXLWLSYVy8EbTdpGbUIG&si=XnJrca02s0BcDpyq). The problem is I was on an older version of Eclipse. I've noticed through my searches eclipse in particular is hard to set up with JavaFX.

So I used the first video in Lukas' tutorial (https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLjN8Vt0x0FFzDTYM0LZg0BNY3n_DKmFcX&si=LQOdhheD4IQFYXnP) to get started, as it specifically dealt with eclipse.
I have updated eclipse, and Java itself (I think) in the process.

I partially completed the first lesson of TheNewBoston's tutorial, resulting in the following code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.*;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class StageManager extends Application {

    private Stage primaryStage;
    
    private Button button;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stageIn) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        primaryStage = stageIn;
        primaryStage.setTitle("Title");
        button = new Button();
        button.setText("Click Me");
        
        StackPane layout = new StackPane();
        layout.getChildren().add(button);
        
        Scene scene = new Scene(layout, 300, 250);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

But now I am getting the following error on running it:

```
Error: LinkageError occurred while loading main class LauncherPackage.StageManager
    java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: javafx/application/Application has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 56.0
```

After some research, it appears I need to update the JRE. I found how to do that in Eclipse ([How to update the JRE in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30388110/how-to-update-the-jre-in-eclipse), https://www.baeldung.com/eclipse-change-java-version), but I've just gotten kinda lost. I've re-downloaded the SDK... I am at a loss for what to do. Where is the JRE? Where am I supposed to download or update it?

Comment: First, see if following the instructions at https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/ can help you.

Comment: Note that the error indicates you're using JavaFX 20+, which requires Java 17+, but you are using Java 12 (an end-of-life version of Java, by the way). I recommend you use Java 21.0.1 (an LTS version, and the latest version as of this comment), though using Java 17.0.X may be acceptable as well (it's also an LTS release). There are many vendors you can download Java from, including [Oracle](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/) and [Eclipse Adoptium](https://adoptium.net/).

Comment: But you may want to consider [BellSoft Liberica](https://bell-sw.com/pages/downloads/) (**Full JDK** package) or [Azul Zulu](https://www.azul.com/downloads/?package=jdk#zulu) (**JDK FX** package), as both provide packages that include JavaFX (meaning you don't have to add JavaFX to your project separately).

Comment: It may be I needed to create a new project. Switching to a IntelliJ IDEA and making a new project got me going again. Goes to show that sometimes an entirely different approach, like switching IDEs, works. Sorry for not being able to figure it out without switching IDEs! Thanks for your help, Slaw!